# How to construct an exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function

I have a set of three points such as $\{(x=1,y=22), (x=2,y=35), (x=3,y=45)\}.$
How to I find the right exponential function to that?

I tried:
... Here I'd like to add a photo of my work but can't upload. I was trying to solve that as a system of three equations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can write your attempt in your question by using mathjax. You can find the guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to take the logarithm of each $y$ and then do a linear regression?

Comment: a pure exponential $y=A B^x$ is not possible as $35^2 \neq 45 \cdot 22$